# Golang HTML template trying to display data based on selection of secondary data

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm not even sure if this is possible with GoLang templates but I am trying to display 2 different select boxes but the second select box displays based on the first select box.

```
// Main category selection
<select name="category_id" id="category_id">
   {{ range $key, $cat := .Data}}
      <option value="{{$cat.ID}}">{{$cat.ID}} - {{$cat.Name}}</option>
   {{end}}
</select>

// Sub-category selection
<select name="sub_category_id" id="sub_category_id">
   {{ range $key, $scat := .Data2}}
      <option value="{{$scat.ID}}">{{$scat.ID}} - {{$scat.Name}}</option>
   {{end}}
</select>
```

As it is right now the sub-category select box will show ALL sub-categories regardless of parent category. Is there a way to show only the sub-categories based on the selection of the main category select box?

example:
select category: 1st-Grade Teachers
select sub-category: (only shows 1st-grade teachers)

Hope I explained this so it's easy to understand what I'm trying to do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a client-side task. Template rendering runs on server side. You have to do this with JavaScript (unless you want to reload the page each time the selection of the first box changes). Register an `onchange` listener for the first box, and change the list of the second in it.